# Create documentation for JetBrains IDE directory

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, doc

When I select a directory in PhpStorm and use `View | Quick Documentation` shortcut it shows `No documentation found` message:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is any way (like IDE settings or installing extra plugins) to create separate documentation for directories?

Comment: I may suggest to create a `readme.md` in the project root folder. The IDE will open such file by default when this project will be opened for the first time. A user can then read your notes about what each folder does. Plus it's  common practice to keep such info there. On the actual subject/question: I know no such plugins or settings.

Comment: This feature works for Java packages with `package-info.java` files with JavaDoc: https://i.imgur.com/9qwE2QR.png. For other languages the special support would be needed in the language support plug-in.